# best way to save child resource Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Father{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =     FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Child> children;
  // other
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Child{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Father father;
  // other
}
```

By using Spring Data REST i can save entity:

Create Father by POST

```
{
"name":"Father1"
}
```

And then create child by POST http://localhost:8080/children/

```
{
"name":"Child1",
"father":"http://localhost:8080/fathers/1"
}
```

Or i can save two independent entities and binds the resource pointed to by the given URI(s) to the resource.

Wich way is the best? 
And i can't understand this: can i add child to father by:

```
curl -X PUT -H "ContentType: text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/children/1 http://localhost:8080/fathers/1/children
```

Comment: Since the relationship is mapped in the child, I assume that you only can set it there by setting the father property. Perhaps with a ManyToMany, this would be different, since then you could first create the entity and then link them, without altering any of them in the process. But honestly, that's just guessing, will have to play around with that, too, so: Good question.

Comment: _"Wich way is the best?"_ by what measure? `PUT` replaces a resource, so to add children the list not only must contain the new children but also the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

At first you created father entity and saved it.

Then you want to bind new child to your child, you will the following in your child create request

```
{
  "father.id": 1,
  "name":"SomeName"
}
```

Spring will automatically convert to father entity when request will be received.